# VirtualBox/Vagrant host only network host doesn't get IP address

Tags: virtualbox, opensuse, vagrant

I'm running Vagrant and VirutalBox and wants to use a host only network. I use the following configuration:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "33.33.33.33"
```

However my host doesn't get an IP address (`33.33.33.1`). Vagrant won't tell me this, I had to run `ip addr` to figure this out. Note that NFS won't work by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to solve this. It is just a stupid error. VirtualBox use the network utility `ifconfig` which is deprecated for many distributions. I had `net-tools` installed which will install `ifconfig` but it looks like not all sub commands are support with this.

The solution is to install `net-tools-deprecated`. https://software.opensuse.org/package/net-tools-deprecated

Comment: There is a bug in Vagrant 1.9.1 which causes almost the same behaviour with Centos boxes see: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8166